wagmi - value return by useReadContract hook is undefined
I don't understand why the setProfile(member[0]) and console.log(member[0]) return the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
the console.log(member), is is ok and returns :
(2) [2, true]
  0: 2
  1: true
  length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

the var 'member' is the result of a useReadContract wagmi hook.
'use client';
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { I4TKnetworkAddress, I4TKnetworkABI } from "@/constants";
import { useAccount, useReadContract } from 'wagmi'
import {config} from '@/app/RainbowKitAndWagmiProvider.js'

const AppContext = createContext({});

export const AppContextProvider =  ({ children }) => {

    const { address } = useAccount()

    const [profile, setProfile] = useState('');

    const { data: member , isSuccess, refetch : refetchProjects} = useReadContract({
        abi: I4TKnetworkABI,
        address: I4TKnetworkAddress,
        functionName: 'Members',
        args: [address],
    });


    useEffect(() => {
    
        console.log(member);
        console.log(member[0]);
       // setProfile(member[0])
    
      }, [isSuccess]);

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{
            address,
            profile,
        }}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );

};

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

thanks for your help
